# Is it possibile to create a custom keyboard for my app?

Tags: android, keyboard

In android, is it possible to create a keyboard only for my application (no need for the other applications to use it)?

I found this project http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/, which creates from scratch a virtual keyboard as a view, but I wonder if this is the only way...

Comment: This could help you http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html

Answer (score 1):

> I found this project http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/, which creates from scratch a virtual keyboard as a view, but I wonder if this is the only way...

Yes. The input method editor (IME) system is only for keyboards available for the whole device.